# Prevent screen-readers / assistive tech from triggering click handler

Tags: ajax, onclick, accessibility, screen-readers, progressive-enhancement

I have this link:

```
<a href="/path/to/page" data-trigger="expedient-element">The Best Page</a>
```

The ajax-populated and -revealed element that exists within the current page is an "enhancement" and has `aria-hidden="true"`. It would be preferable for screen-readers and assistive tech to follow the link's href to the subsequent static page, rather than triggering the click handler (especially since the element that it will acts on is already hidden, as previously mentioned).

Will this behavior already take place or do I need to add something?

Comment: Can you provide an example of why you are hiding the content for screen reader users as this is not a good practice (providing one experience for non screen reader users and one for screen reader users is a last resort), are you trying to load some content in via AJAX or something and trying to provide this as a fallback? (as you don't need to do that!)

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I have several instances and all are calling a majority of content from the linked pages. I don't really want to get into the murk of accessible modals and dialogs, I'd rather just send the relevant users to the perfectly accessible pages:)

Comment: Just for clarity, this is just content that is loaded in via AJAX? If so then the solution is actually much simpler, manage focus when the content loads. Let me know and I will drop you a full answer this evening (out all day) explaining how to handle AJAX content insertion correctly. If you need to 'get on with it', simply add `tabindex="0"` to a heading (add a visually hidden heading if you don't have one) on the AJAX loaded content, when you click the link just set focus using JavaScript on that heading when the AJAX call is complete and it will work fine. Better experience than page load.

Comment: No worries @GrahamRitchie — I understand what you are getting at but with the greatest respect, you're answering an altogether different question from the one posed.

Comment: I am doing that as what you propose is a bad practice, if you really must do it then why not check for 'enter' or 'space' clicks and intercept them to navigate as normal as most screen reader users will use a keyboard. Obviously this doesn't account for screen magnifier users who will struggle to work out where the content has loaded (as they only see 10% of the screen at a time), which is why I am attempting to lead you to a much better solution rather than giving an answer that may not improve accessibility. Not trying to change your question :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When pressing enter on a link, it does the same as a click, and it's a very bad idea to intercept the enter key in order to do something different.

- There are keyboard users, perfectly sighted, who aren't using screen reader. These users will experience an unexpected behavior.
- Screen readers may choose to send directly a click event, rather than keyboard events, even though enter has been actually pressed. So idem in the opposite direction.
- There may be other ways to activate a link, other than click or enter: spacebar, tap on touch screen, assistive techs to click by winking the eyes, etc. How it should behave in these cases ?

By the way, you can't do something different based on whether a screen reader is used or not, simply because you have no 100% reliable way to detect it.

The questions you should ask yourself are:

- Why do you want a different behavior between click and enter ? or between screen reader and normal users ?
- Are you trying to work around inaccessible content, or do you have two versions of the same content (an accessible and a unaccessible one) ? In that case, it would be much better to have a single content and make it accessible. Rare are the cases where it's really impossible, and experience shows that the two versions are eventually going to be out of sync, more quicker than you think.